# Google Plus API: Find people following a particular person

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, google-plus

I know this feature may not yet be part of the official API, but has anyone successfully figured out how to extract a list of people who "follow" a particular user, or rather have placed that user in one or more of their circles?  I'm using the official JS Library, but I'll take any answer with any language since it certainly could be adapted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is no way through the API to this list.

You would need to scrap the content of the about page of a user, but you will be limited to only a part of the followers.

Like described [here](https://plus.google.com/+MaxHuijgen/posts/ifFxu72ZtAw) even the user himself can't get the full list of his followers.